# change double letters in string

Tags: javascript

I'm making (trying to make) a function which can return an array with the characters of a word. It needs to save some double letters as one in the array. I have an array which contains the double letters. I have a list of words (somethimes big). The problem now is that it saves the first letter 2 times and it saves the double chars from the word in the array called letters. The function itself is running in a loop which gets the words from a json object. The function is made in the way that I could think of, but if there's a better way (obviously) please tell me how.

The function:

```
var word = 'voorheen';
var doubles = ['aa', 'oo', 'ee', 'ie', 'oe', 'eu', 'uu', 'au', 'ou', 'ui', 'ng', 'ch',   'ij'];
var letters = getLetters(word, doubles);
console.log(letters);

function getLetters(word, doubles) { 
var letters = [];
var specials = [];
var indexes = [];
for(var s=0;s<doubles.length;s++) {
    if(word.indexOf(doubles[s]) != -1) {
        specials.push(doubles[s]); 
        indexes.push(word.indexOf(doubles[s])); 
        console.log('specials: ' + specials);           
        console.log('indexes: ' + indexes);          
    }
}   
for(var i=0;i<word.length;i++) { 
    if(specials.length>0) {
        for(var j=0;j<specials.length;j++) {
            if(i<indexes[j]) {
                letters.push(word[i]);  
                console.log('i: ' + i);
                console.log('j: ' + j);
                console.log('letter: ' + word[i]);
            }    
            if(i==indexes[j]) {
                letters.push(specials[j]);
                console.log('i: ' + i);
                console.log('j: ' + j);
                console.log('letter: ' + word[i]);                  
            }
            if(i>indexes[j] + specials[j].length) { 
                letters.push(word[i]);
                console.log('i: ' + i);
                console.log('j: ' + j);
                console.log('letter: ' + word[i]);                  
            }

        }
    }
    else {
        letters.push(word[i]);
    }       
}
return letters;
}
```

Chrome log output of letters:

```
["v", "v", "oo", "o", "o", "r", "h", "h", "e", "ee", "e", "n"]
```

While i want:

```
 ["v", "oo", "r", "h", "ee", "n"]
```

Comment: what is input and what output do you want?

Comment: Becuase i have no problem using jquery if it makes it more easy to create a function that does what i need.

Comment: What if your doubles array had a **'rh'** in it? Would it make the final output `["v", "oo", "rh", "ee", "n"] `?

Comment: @VJD the input is a word (in the above function it is voorheen)and an array with the double letters. the output should be as above.

Comment: @c.O.u1 Yes that is exactly what im trying to get.

Comment: You will find it much easier to debug if you put some indication of line number or code path in your `console.log`, e.g. `console.log('i<indexes[j]', i, j, 'letter: ' + word[i]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var word = 'voorheen';
var doubles = ['aa','oo','ee','ie','oe','eu','uu','au','ou','ui','ng','ch','ij'];
var letters = word.match(new RegExp(doubles.join("|")+"|.","g")) || [];
```

Regexes capture as much as possible (unless specifically declared ungreedy), so the two-letter combinations take precedence over the `.` that matches any single character.

Bonus points because this can be expanded to include combinations of any length :p

Comment: The capturing group is unnecessary, and don't forget a trailing `|| []` after the match attempt (for empty words)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that should work without regexs and in POJS

Javascript

```
function stringToFormattedArray(string) {
    var doubles = ['aa', 'oo', 'ee', 'ie', 'oe', 'eu', 'uu', 'au', 'ou', 'ui', 'ng', 'ch', 'ij'],
        result = [],
        chars,
        pair;

    while (string) {
        pair = string.slice(0, 2);
        if (doubles.indexOf(pair) !== -1) {
            result.push(pair);
            string = string.slice(2);
        } else {
            result.push(pair.split("")[0]);
            string = string.slice(1);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(stringToFormattedArray("voorheen"));
```

Output

```
["v", "oo", "r", "h", "ee", "n"]
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Gawmk/)

Note: [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) can be shimmed, either by that supplied on MDN or by [es5_shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim). Or of course you could loop through the array manually and perform `===`

Update: without `Array.prototype.indexOf`

Javascript

```
function stringToFormattedArray(string) {
    var doubles = ['aa', 'oo', 'ee', 'ie', 'oe', 'eu', 'uu', 'au', 'ou', 'ui', 'ng', 'ch', 'ij'],
        length = doubles.length,
        result = [],
        chars,
        pair,
        i;

    while (string) {
        pair = string.slice(0, 2);

        i = 0;
        while (i < length) {
            if (pair === doubles[i]) {
                result.push(pair);
                string = string.slice(2);
                break;
            }

            i += 1;
        }

        if (i === length) {
            result.push(pair.split("")[0]);
            string = string.slice(1);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(stringToFormattedArray("voorheen"));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Ej26P/)

Update: for pure interest sake, I created a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-function-format-string) that tests the regex version versus the above for the specific string "vorheen".

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your iteration over `specials` you're pushing the letters every time if it is not at the current `indexes[j]`. Since your `specials` has two members, every letter will get doubled up.

To fix that, you would need a flag whether the current letter should be pushed or not that is set during that loop. Btw, your approach with the indices is flawed anyway, as it doesn't cope with repeating doubles (e.g. `oohoo`). Better:

```
function getLetters(word, doubles) {
    var letters = [];
    for (var i=0; i<word.length; i++) {
        var next = word.slice(i, i+2);
        if (doubles.indexOf(next) >= 0) {
            letters.push(next);
            i++;
        } else
            letters.push(word.charAt(i));
    }
    return letters;
}
```

A regex-based matcher would be much simpler:

```
var word = 'voorheen',
    letters = word.match(/aa|oo|ee|ie|oe|eu|uu|au|ou|ui|ng|ch|ij|\S/g) || [];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also make it too complicated.

Just try something as below : http://jsfiddle.net/jHjkQ/

```
var word = 'voorheen';
var doubles = ['aa', 'oo', 'ee', 'ie', 'oe', 'eu', 'uu', 'au', 'ou', 'ui', 'ng', 'ch',   'ij'];
var result = [];
for(var i=0; i < word.length;i++) {
    var nextI = i + 1;
    //as double it must be first if you going to implement triple add above this line...
    if (nextI < word.length && doubles.indexOf(word[i] + "" + word[nextI]) > -1) {
        result.push(doubles[doubles.indexOf(word[i] + "" + word[nextI])]);
        i++; //double ignore next one
    }
    else {
        result.push(word[i]);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This relies on the browser knowing `Array.prototype.indexOf`, which is not true of older versions of IE.

Comment: in this case you can use jQuery.inArray("aa", arr) instead.

Comment: Because, of course, jQuery is the answer to everything. Especially when there's an infinitely simpler solution in [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/)